# ID Confirm System Def(). Problems with many variables, f.read()

Tags: python

I'm building a Confirm ID while app is running function.
And the problems is that when the code is running, and when the code is not correct in the first time, the code sees it as I'm writing the incorrect code the third time, and automatically uses system.exit which is in the code. What's the problem here?

```
import sys
import math
import os
import ctypes
import getpass
banmsg = 'pzdcnu'
DuomenuBaz = 'accountfile.txt'
Ban = False


class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self):
        self._balance = 0.00

    def get_balance(self):
        return self._balance

    def increase_balance(self, amount):
        self._balance += amount

    def decrease_balance(self, amount):
        self._balance -= amount

Cash = BankAccount()

def clear(): return os.system('clear')
check = True
print("~ Welcome to Ship.EU\n To register simply create a nickname\n If you have one you'l be transfered to Login Screen.")
while check:
    Vartotojo_Vardas = input("Please enter your name\n").lower()
    Vartotojo_Pass = getpass.getpass("Please enter your password\n")
    if " " in Vartotojo_Pass or " " in Vartotojo_Vardas or len(Vartotojo_Vardas) <3 or len(Vartotojo_Pass) <3:
        print("Error!")
        continue
    else:
        Vartotojo_ID = input("~ Create Security ID Code for your account!")
        if " " in Vartotojo_ID or len(Vartotojo_ID) != 3:
            print("ID MUST BE NOT LESS THAN 3 SYMBOLL.")
            continue
        else:
            with open(DuomenuBaz,mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
                if "Vardas: "+ Vartotojo_Vardas in f.read():
                    clear()
                    print("~ Username {} exists, please Log-IN".format(Vartotojo_Vardas))
                    Login1 = input("~ Please enter your password\n").lower()
                    f.close()
                    with open(DuomenuBaz, mode="r", encoding = 'utf-8') as ACCLOGIN:
                        for line in ACCLOGIN:
                            if "Vardas: "+Vartotojo_Vardas + " Password: " + Login1 in line.strip():
                                clear()
                                check = False
                                Cash.increase_balance(20)
                                print("Successfully logged in as {}".format(Vartotojo_Vardas))
                                ACCLOGIN.close()
                                break
                            else:
                                clear()
                                print("Incorrect Login!")
                                continue
                else:
                    with open(DuomenuBaz, mode = 'a', encoding = 'UTF-8') as f:
                        Ban = True
                        f.write(f"\nVardas: {Vartotojo_Vardas} Password: {Vartotojo_Pass} ID: {Vartotojo_ID} Balance EUR {Cash.get_balance()} Ban: {Ban} ")
                        print("Vardas {} Password {} ID {} Ban {} Created!".format(Vartotojo_Vardas, Vartotojo_Pass, Vartotojo_ID,Ban))
                        f.close()
                    break
if Ban:
    Unban_MSG = input("~ Your account is banned!\n May you Want to Unban? (Y,N)\n").lower()
    if "y" in Unban_MSG:
        Ban = False
        print("~ You're unbanned")
    elif "n" in Unban_MSG:  
        print("~ BAN")
        sys.exit
else:
    print("~ You're clean@!")


Acccount_Status = print("BAN - {} Balance - {}".format(Ban, Cash.get_balance()))

checkas = True
while checkas:
    Attempts = 30
    CurrentAttemp = 0
    KickForBadCode = sys.exit
    IDConfirm = input("* [3NEMATIX]: {} Please confirm Your ID CODE... ".format(Vartotojo_Vardas))
    with open (DuomenuBaz, mode = 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as Confirm:
        for line in Confirm:
            if "Vardas: " + Vartotojo_Vardas + " Password: " + Vartotojo_Pass + " ID: " + IDConfirm in line.strip():
                print("Correct!")
                Confirm.close()
            else:
                clear()
                CurrentAttemp += 1
                if CurrentAttemp > 3:
                    print("~ You have been kicked for too many attempts!")
                    KickForBadCode
                elif CurrentAttemp is not 3:
                    print("Wrong Attempt! {}/{}".format(CurrentAttemp,Attempts))
```

Comment: Could you post your whole code please

Comment: Updated @system123456